# SQL join query with exception over 'on'

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a SQL query wherein I am using inner join and using 2 conditions in Join but it is creating a column value to show all NULL values, but I want NULL values as well.

Join Query :-

```
from spend_v1 a
        inner join spend_v2 b
        on a.Primary_Brand=b.Primary_Brand
        and a.Market=b.Market
```

If I use this query then a column `T-Type` is showing NULL values only as if `Market` is matching for both tables, then the Output of query **shows the rows of `T-Type` which is NULL, but I want the Not NULL values as well.**

Also, only the `Market` & `Primary_Brand` columns are matching in both tables, so I need to keep them.

How can I create that exception in my query so that the `T-Type` column having NOT NULL values also comes in the output. ?

**Full Query :-**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('spend_v1') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE spend_v1; 

select distinct A.Primary_Brand_Key, A.Year, A.Month, A.Category, Medium ,A.Market,b.Sub_Category, b.Segment as Segment, b.Sub_Segment as Sub_Segment, b.Big_C, b.Small_C,
case T_Type when 'TRAE' then 'FA'  end as T_Type,
--T_Type,
concat(Month,' ',Year) as Period_Type,
CASE WHEN A.Market='AP / Telangana' THEN 'Cluster'
 WHEN A.Market='Assam / North East / Sikkim' THEN 'Cluster' 
 WHEN A.Market='Bihar/Jharkhand' THEN 'Cluster'
 WHEN A.Market='Guj / D&D / DNH' THEN 'Cluster'
 WHEN A.Market='Karnataka' THEN 'Cluster'
 WHEN A.Market='Kerala' THEN 'Cluster'
 WHEN A.Market='Mah / Goa' THEN 'Cluster'
 WHEN A.Market='MP/Chhattisgarh' THEN 'Cluster'
 WHEN A.Market='Odisha' THEN 'Cluster'
 WHEN A.Market='Pun / Har / Cha / HP / J&K' THEN 'Cluster'
 WHEN A.Market='Rajasthan' THEN 'Cluster' 
 WHEN A.Market='TN/Pondicherry' THEN 'Cluster'
 WHEN A.Market='UP/Uttarakhand' THEN 'Cluster' 
 WHEN A.Market='West Bengal' THEN 'Cluster'
 WHEN A.Market='Delhi' THEN 'Cluster'
 WHEN A.Market='Bangalore' THEN 'Metro'
 WHEN A.Market='Chennai' THEN 'Metror' 
 WHEN A.Market='Hyderabad' THEN 'Metro'
 WHEN A.Market='Kolkata' THEN 'Metro'
 WHEN A.Market='Mumbai' THEN 'Metro'
 WHEN A.Market='All India' THEN 'Geo' END as Geography_Type,
A.LSM as Target_Group
into spend_v1 
from dtr.UL_MEDIA_IN_PBRT_SPENDS a
left join
dtr.UL_MEDIA_IN_PBRT_BRAND_HIERARCHY_MASTER b
on a.Category = b.Small_C and a.Primary_Brand_Key = b.PBRT_KEY
group by A.Primary_Brand_Key, A.Year, A.Month, A.Category, Medium ,A.Market,b.Sub_Category, b.Segment , b.Sub_Segment, b.Big_C, b.Small_C,
T_Type, LSM
--select * from spend_v1
--where T_Type is not NULL


IF OBJECT_ID('spend_v2') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE spend_v2; 

select distinct Primary_Brand_Key,year, month, category,   Market, 
sum(case when (Medium in ('TV') and Market is not NULL ) then Amount_Spent else 0 end) as TV_Spends,
sum(case when (Medium in ('Print') and Market is not NULL ) then Amount_Spent else 0 end) as Print_Spends,
sum(case when (Medium in ('Radio') and Market is not NULL ) then Amount_Spent else 0 end) as Radio_Spends,
sum(case when (Medium in ('Cinema') and Market is not NULL ) then Amount_Spent else 0 end) as Cinema_Spends,
sum(case when (Medium in ('Mobile') and Market is not NULL ) then Amount_Spent else 0 end) as Mobile_Spends,
sum(case when (Medium in ('YT') and Market is not NULL ) then Amount_Spent else 0 end) as YouTube_Spends,
sum(case when (Medium in ('OTT') and Market is not NULL ) then Amount_Spent else 0 end) as OTT_Spends,
sum(case when (Medium in ('FB') and Market is not NULL ) then Amount_Spent else 0 end) as Facebook_Spends,
sum(case when (Medium in ('OOH') and Market is not NULL ) then Amount_Spent else 0 end) as OOH_Spends,
sum(case when (Medium in ('Others') and Market is not NULL ) then Amount_Spent else 0 end) as Others_Spends,
sum(case when (Medium in ('YT', 'OTT', 'FB') and Market is not NULL ) then Amount_Spent else 0 end) as Digital_Spends,
sum(Amount_Spent) as Total_Spends
into spend_v2 
from dtr.UL_MEDIA_IN_PBRT_SPENDS
group by year, month, category,  Primary_Brand_Key, Market
order by Primary_Brand_Key, Market;

--select * from spend_v2
--order by Primary_Brand_Key, Market

select distinct A.Primary_Brand_Key as Primary_Brand , A.Year, A.Month, A.Category, A.Market, IsNull(A.Sub_Category, '')as Sub_Category, IsNull(A.Segment, '') as Segment, IsNull(A.Sub_Segment, '') as Sub_Segment, 
IsNull(A.Big_C, '') as Big_C, IsNull(A.Small_C, '') as Small_C,
A.T_Type, A.Period_Type, IsNull(A.Geography_Type, '')as Geography_Type, IsNull(A.Target_Group, '') as Target_Group, --A.Sub_Category,-- A.new_segment as new_segment, A.Sub_Segment, 
B.TV_Spends,
 B.Print_Spends,
  B.Radio_Spends,
        B.Cinema_Spends,
      B.Mobile_Spends,
      B.Youtube_Spends,
       B.OTT_Spends,
        B.Facebook_Spends,
 B.OOH_Spends,
       B.Others_Spends,
        B.Digital_Spends,
        Total_Spends

        --into dtr.UL_MEDIA_IN_PBRT_SPENDS_OUTPUT

        from spend_v1 a
        inner join spend_v2 b
        on (a.Primary_Brand_Key=b.Primary_Brand_Key
        and a.Market=b.Market)
        or a.T_Type is NOT NULL
        --and a.Category=b.Category
        --and a.T_Type is not NULL
        --or a.Market!=b.Market
        --and T_Type is NULL
        --where T_Type is NOT NULL

        group by A.Primary_Brand_Key, A.Year, A.Month, A.Category, A.Market, Sub_Category, Segment , Sub_Segment, Big_C, Small_C,
        T_Type, Period_Type, Geography_Type, Target_Group,
        TV_spends, Print_Spends, Radio_Spends, Cinema_Spends, Mobile_Spends, Youtube_Spends, OTT_Spends,  Facebook_Spends, OOH_Spends,  Others_Spends,  Digital_Spends, Total_Spends
        order by A.Primary_Brand_Key, Market
```

Comment: There is no point to debugging fragments of a query. Post a complete query that reproduces your problem as a script (or fiddle) that others can use.  No one but you knows which tables contain the column T-Type.

Comment: @SMor : I added the whole query now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below code :

```
from spend_v1 a
        inner join spend_v2 b
        on (a.Primary_Brand=b.Primary_Brand
        and a.Market=b.Market) or [t-type] is null
```

Comment: Worked liked Charm. Many thanks, @Ravikiran.

However, after some verification, I am finding some duplicates or data discrepancies where ```T_Type is NOT NULL ```.

I have added the SQL query for better understanding of my code

Comment: If t-type is null what are the values you are expecting from table spend_v2 ? If you want the values from spend_v2 to be NULL then you can use UNION ALL. Join will not help. Now you are getting duplicates because the SQL is not able to decide which entries from spend_v2 has to be picked for t-type NULL entries. Hope I am clear

Comment: I understood you @Ravikiran.

However, if I try Union then the no. of  columns will not match for both the tables.

Is there any other way possible?

Comment: Use union all and map NULL to the columns from second table.